# Merging two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I've seen this question a few times, but the answers are not working for me.  I have two dataframes, `split_df` and `csv_df` that I;m trying to merge on a column that is called `key` in each of them.

Here's the top 5 items from `split_df`

```
        key        tags
2785  30000        ipv6
2785  30000  networking
2785  30000    wireless
2785  30000   standards
2785  30000      satcom
```

Here's the top 5 items from the `csv_df`

```
     key
0  30000
1  30002
2  31288
3  33630
4  31663
```

When I run this merge statement:

```
common_df = pd.merge(split_df,csv_df, on=['key'], suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
```

I get:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [key, tags]
Index: []
```

Process finished with exit code 0

I can't figure out why the merge isn't working for me.  Any suggestions?

I have indexes on both (and have run the merge with them out as well)

```
csv_df.set_index('key')
split_df.set_index('key')
```

I am very new to Pyton and Pandas

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the above code this works for me:

```
In [11]: pd.merge(split_df,csv_df, on=['key'], suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
Out[11]:
     key        tags
0  30000        ipv6
1  30000  networking
2  30000    wireless
3  30000   standards
4  30000      satcom
```

My suspicion is that the column type `key` is different in your dataframes (and the same `int` in mine).

Most likely one of them is a string (and the other a float/int).

```
In [12]: split_df["key"] = split_df["key"].apply(str)

In [13]: pd.merge(split_df,csv_df, on=['key'], suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
Out[13]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [key, tags]
Index: []
```

If they're both strings:

```
In [14]: csv_df["key"] = csv_df["key"].apply(str)

In [15]: pd.merge(split_df,csv_df, on=['key'], suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
Out[15]:
     key        tags
0  30000        ipv6
1  30000  networking
2  30000    wireless
3  30000   standards
4  30000      satcom
```

Comment: check with `splitt_df.dtypes` and `csv_df.dtypes`

Answer (score 3):

The `key` column in one of your dataframes is `int` while the other is `str`

```
split_df.key = split_df.key.astype(int)
csv_df.key = csv_df.key.astype(int)

pd.merge(split_df,csv_df, on=['key'], suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
```

Comment: Thanks you - that was it :-)